# Symfony getName() not working inside of controller

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I am trying to access getName() in my controller, but it is not working.

This **DOESN'T** work:

```
 $supplier = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')->findBy(array('account'=>$account_id, 'id'=>$id));
 $supplierName = $supplier->getName();
 This doesnt return the name from the db....
 I get the error: "Error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object..."
```

This **DOES** works:

```
 $supplier = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')->find($id);
 $supplierName = $supplier->getName();
 This returns the name from the db....
```

Why?

Comment: In first case - returned var type is array, not object? Try var_dump?

Answer (score 5):

findBy returns an array, not an object. Do you mean findOneBy?

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#querying

Answer (score 1):

Because "findBy" is returns a collection / array. On your working example (find); it's only looks for exact "one" result referencing by ID field and you can directly call getters (getName()) from defined variable.

Or you can use findOneBy to look one result by different conditions.

If you want to get different supplier names you have to use foreach function to reach to each entity.

For example :

```
foreach($supplier as $s)
{
   echo $s->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Jessica's answer, the `findBy()` repository method will return an array of objects that are an instance of your `Supplier` entity, whereas `find()` will return a single entity. If you're expecting only one, just call the getName method on the first one.

```
$suppliers = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')
    ->findBy(array(
        'account' => $account_id,
        'id'      => $id
    ));

if (count($suppliers) < 1) {
    // Assuming the code is in a controller
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No such supplier found.'); 
}

$supplierName = $suppliers[0]->getName();
```

Or better yet, `findOneBy()`

```
$supplier = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')
    ->findOneBy(array(
        'account' => $account_id,
        'id'      => $id
    ));

if (!$supplier) {
    throw $this->createNotFoundException('No such supplier found.'); 
}

$supplierName = $supplier->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$supplier = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')->findBy(array('account'=>$account_id, 'id'=>$id));
$supplierName = $supplier->getName();
```

With:

```
$supplier = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')->findOneBy(array('account'=>$account_id, 'id'=>$id));
$supplierName = $supplier->getName();
```

Answer (score -2):

<strike>I looked around, i think you need to use multiple arrays,</strike>

```
$supplier = $em->getRepository('WICSupplierBundle:Supplier')
->findBy(
array('account'=>$account_id),  ##  array 1 
array('id'=>$id)                ##  array 2
);
```

$supplierName = $supplier->getName();

Update:
Ok after re-reading the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/doctrine.html) again I noticed that the second array is for sorting.